# os module missing getresuid() method in python

Tags: python

I'm learning python. when I ran the code below, I got some problem. It seems that some methods in `os` module are missing. Here's the code:

```
import os
import time

print("process ruid is {}, euid is {}, suid is {}\ngid is {}, egid is{}, sgid is {}".format(*os.getresuid()+os.getresgid()))
pid = os.fork()
if pid:
    print("the main process euid is {}, gid is {}, id is {}, pgid is {}".format(os.geteuid(),os.getgid(), os.getpid(), os.getpgrp()))
    os._exit(0)  # kill original process
print("the child process euid is {}, gid is {}, id is {}, original pgid is {}".format(os.geteuid(),os.getgid(),os.getpid(), os.getpgrp()))
print "daemon started, now change the pgid of child process and let it become the leader process of a new group"
success =  os.setpgrp()
# success = os.setpgid(0, 0)
if success:
    print "get some problem here"
print("the child process euid is {}, gid is {}, id is {}, pgid is {}".format(os.geteuid(),os.getgid(),os.getpid(), os.getpgrp()))
time.sleep(10)
print "daemon terminated"
```

Exceptions are like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Example/Example1_40.py", line 4, in <module>
    print("process ruid is {}, euid is {}, suid is {}\ngid is {}, egid is{}, sgid is {}".format(*os.getresuid()+os.getresgid()))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getresuid'
```

And I test the `os` module in Python shell with `dir(os)`, I've found that the methods are really not there. Can anyone tell me, what's the problem. And I'm working on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2, and I use Pyenv to install Python. both Python2 and Python3 seem to have this problem.

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: @DavidG nope, I'm working on macOS. Any clues?  : )

Comment: It is not present in OSX: https://bugs.python.org/msg91837. You may also find this useful: https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg/pull/28

Comment: @DavidG macOS is a unix-like OS, It's built on Darwin, some kind of BSD system, I think.

Comment: http://andre.stechert.org/urwhatu/2006/10/getting_the_sav.html

Comment: Also BSD != Unix

Comment: @BaileyParker Yeah, You're right. maybe strictly speaking, BSD-like. But I just want to know, it only happens on my computer or all macOS platform is not supported?

Comment: As @AshwiniChaudhary tried to tell you. It is not present on macOS at all. So yes, it happens on your system, because it doesn't exist. Check my link for a C workaround that you can probably port.

Comment: @BaileyParker I'm sorry, there's some delay here. I just see it. those methods are just not supported for mac. pity.  But thank you all the same.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks for your great help.